# run mysql update query using powershell script

Tags: mysql, powershell

I'm trying to run the update query after running the mysql scripts in mysql db using powershell script, below mentioned query i am trying

```
Invoke-MySqlQuery -Query "UPDATE $DataBase.tablename SET account=$Storageacc,primary_key = $StorageKey,blob_container= $Container WHERE id = 1 and name = 'testing'"
```

when i run the above query using powershell script iam getting below error

The term `'Invoke-MySqlQuery'` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again

Comment: even i tried another way as well :- run-MySQLQuery -ConnectionString "$Connectionstring" -Query "UPDATE $DataBase.tablename SET account=$Storageacc,primary_key = $StorageKey,blob_container= $Container WHERE id = 1 and name = 'testing'"  still iam getting error ##[error]The term 'run-MySQLQuery' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: I just need to the proper update query syntax of mysql using powershell script

Answer (score 1):

You are missing module or software which is needed to interact with Powershell. Please check this: [Querying MySQL Database with Powershell](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/03/02/querying-mysql-databases.aspx)

Comment: No we have added module..thats why we are able to run the scripts

Comment: Get-Module -ListAvailable ----- to check if the module is imported. If it is giving you that error message, it means that the cmdlet is not there.

Answer (score 0):

The error means the module is either not installed/present on your machine or has not been imported into the powershell session.

What does Get-Module display?